# Why script.js is not loading on every component without refresh in angular cli 17.0.5

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using Angular cli 17.0.5 I have started one application. In that application have Login, Registration, Home and others page. In home page I have added header, footer and left side menu but in login and registration page I cannot. For that I have created another components name is landing component. In landing component, I have added common section like

<app-header class="header-section"></app-header>

<app-left-menu class="left-section-template"></app-left-menu>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-sponsor-ads></app-sponsor-ads>

In home page I have written middle part of the page, in this way I have created number of components.

In the app.component.html I have written

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

App.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [

{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

{ path: 'registration', component:RegistrationComponent }

{

path: '',

component:LandingComponent,

children:[

{ path: 'home', component:HomeComponent},

{ path: 'trending-view', component:TrendingViewComponent}

]

},

{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/neuihome', pathMatch: 'full' }

];

Under assets folder I have created script.js. In script I have written page interaction part. That script I have added in angular.json file.

"scripts": [

"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",

"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

"src/assets/js/otp-verify.js",

"src/assets/js/main.min.js",

"src/assets/js/script.js",

"src/assets/js/jquery-stories.js",

"src/assets/js/toast-notificatons.js",

"src/assets/js/map-init.js",

"src/assets/js/page-tourintro.js",

"src/assets/js/page-tour-init.js",

"src/assets/js/TweenMax.min.js",

"src/assets/js/header_section.js"

]

When application is running on localhost:4200 first time script in loading but when I click on any menu at that time without refresh script.js is not loading so my page interaction in not working.

Comment: try ./src/assets/js/script.js